# Is every weak contraction a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis

A weak contraction is a function $f:M \to M$ such that for all $x \neq y$, $d(f(x), f(y)) < d(x, y)$. I don't think every weak contraction is a contraction, but I'm having a hard time finding a counterexample. Also, is it true that if $M$ is compact, then a weak contraction is a contraction? I think it might be true, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: I think this(6c) is a fun example, if you are into algebraic topology... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481001/hatchers-algebraic-topology-problem-0-6bc-is-this-proof-legit?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, a weak contraction need not be a contraction, not even when the domain is compact. For instance, let $M=[0,1/2]$ with the usual metric, and let $f:M\to M$ be $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f$ is a weak contraction since $|x^2-y^2|=|x-y||x+y| < |x-y|$ when $x\ne y\in [0,1/2]$. However, it is not a contraction since for any $0 < \alpha<1$ the inequality $|f(x)-f(y)|\le \alpha |x-y|$ doesn't hold for all $x,y\in [0,1/2)$. This is so since for $x,y\in (1/2-\epsilon /2, 1/2)$, for $1>\epsilon >0$, holds that $|x^2-y^2|=|x-y|\cdot |x+y|>|x-y|\cdot (1-\epsilon)$ (assuming $x\ne y)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. can you perhaps shed some light on whether a weak contraction is a contraction when M is compact?

Comment: You have a typo: you meant the inequality to be strict where you claim the weak contraction.

Comment: @AdenDong I just improved the answer slightly to answer that as well.

Comment: @julien thank you! I corrected the typo.

Comment: @IttayWeiss thank you! great counterexample. i always have trouble doing those questions that ask you to find counterexamples...

Comment: Excuse me, please. Can we say that since there is fixed point, then it`s a contraction?

Comment: Let $\alpha=7/12, x=1/3, y=1/4$

Comment: @guest: no, existence of fixed point does not imply a map is a contraction.

Comment: Let me just add a comment to Ittay's counterexample: the main driving force is that the definition of weak contraction as stated in the problem is given on the set $M\times M\setminus D$, where $D = \{(x,x)\}$ is the diagonal set. Now while $M$ being compact would imply $M\times M$ is compact, to draw the conclusion along the line the OP imagined requires knowing that $M\times M\setminus D$ is compact, which is not guaranteed by our assumptions thus far.