# Contraction mapping on metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

We know the definition of contraction mapping. But it is unkown to me the definition of weak contraction mapping. Help me

Comment: May be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310786/is-every-weak-contraction-a-contraction) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A mapping $f:X\rightarrow X $ on a metric space is a $\bf{weak} $ contraction if for all $x\neq y\in X$ you have
$$d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$$
whereas a contraction is such a mapping  where there is a constant $0<C<1$ so that
$$d(f(x),f(y))\leq Cd(x,y)$$
for $\bf{all}$ $x,y\in X$. The answer I cited in the comment shows not every weak contraction is a contraction.